# Unfortunately, my app has stopped in a simple app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am learning android programming in android studio, and I am trying to do a simple app, just an activity for login and if is correct then show the main activity.

The first part I did is the main activity, with some layouts just trying to show some images that are in the drawable folder in the project, but I can not even start the form. I use genimotion and it says "Unfortunately, Imagenes has stopped" Imagenes is the name of my project. I just begin learning so maybe there is something I forgot but I can not realize by myself.
Site:sidneylc.com   Proyect name:Imagenes

Here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.sidneylc.imagenes.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ciudad1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Dubai"
                android:background="#212fcc"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ciudad2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Seul"
                android:background="#1bd2cd"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/paisaje1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Paisaje1"
                android:background="#f70d5b"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/paisaje2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Paisaje2"
                android:background="#64e623"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/montana1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Montana1"
            android:background="#fdd835"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/montana2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Montana2"
            android:background="#fdd835"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And when I tried it show the app for less than a second and then says "Unfortunately, Imagenes has stopped"

I had to upload the logcat to gist because it exceeded the 30k limit of characters, In total logcat is more than 60k lines.
Here is the link:
https://gist.github.com/Sidneylc/5f36836147d3683856e7cb111dfc228e

I could not find how to format it as code. Thanks.

Comment: `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout`

Comment: Welcome Sidney. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Take time to review your work and proof read before posting. Also make a minimal example - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can u please post Activity code ..

Comment: Okay tahnks for the advice, I was trying to put every detail, I would be put more details in the future, thanks.

Comment: `1114088592` that's a big image...

Comment: Yes, then I realized by the answers here. I finally got the app running, because in the preview it looks great. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using huge images and getting out of memory. Just resize your images and try again.

Comment: This could be a comment..!!

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to just the main layout that contains a relative layout for each image or text I needed, I also reduced the image size to the size of the parent layout. Thanks for the answer, and the idea.